# vue ui Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/proposals/array-flat-and-flat-map'

Tags: vuejs2

I'm starting to learn Vue.js but when I try to launch vue ui, I get this error:
**Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/proposals/array-flat-and-flat-map'**
I tried to npm install -g core-js and yet still the same error.
my npm version is 6.4.1
Thanks for your anwsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a temp workaround while they work on resolving the underlying issue:

```
npm install -g core-js@3.0.0-beta.11
```

That temp resolution comes from this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3406#issuecomment-459956718